# X86-64 Inline Assembly in C (compiled using GCC), multi-precision multiplication routine causing a seg fault

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, gmp

I'm trying to implement multi-precision multiplication of GMP `mpz_t` objects in inline X86 Assembly. Depending on my choice of constraints on the output variable, I either get a segmentation fault, or the values in the output variable get corrupted in an inconsistent way (*i.e. different runs of the code cause the values to get corrupted differently*).

What this code does is take two GMP `mpz_t` objects, `ain` and `bin`, that are each guaranteed to have size 13 (i.e. `_mp_size` is set to 13, the objects are defined by 13, 64 bit numbers) and then produce an `mpz_t` object of size 26, res, that is the result of multiplying `ain` and `bin` together. The reason I do not use `mpz_mul` is because this method usually results in a performance increase in this particular setting.

Note that `res->_mp_d, ain->_mp_d` and `bin->_mp_d` refer to the array of "limbs" that define the respective `mpz_t` objects, with `(obj->_mp_d)[0]` being the least significant limb and `(obj->_mp_d)[obj->_mp_size-1]` being the most significant limb.

If anyone can help explain what I am doing wrong here, I would really appreciate it! Below is a code segment. I have excluded most the assembly because it is repetitive, but I think I give enough to give a good indication of what is going on:

```
void mpz_mul_x86_1(mpz_t res, mpz_t ain, mpz_t bin){

   if( res->_mp_alloc<26) //the next few lines makes sure res is large enough
     _mpz_realloc(res,26); //the result of the multiplication

   res->_mp_size = 26;


   asm volatile (            
     "movq 0(%1), %%rax;" 
     "mulq 0(%2);"
     "movq %%rax, 0(%0);"    
     "movq %%rdx, %%r8;"           //A0*B0
                                   //0

     "xorq %%r10, %%r10;" 

     "movq 8(%1), %%rax;"      
     "mulq 0(%2);"              
     "addq %%rax, %%r8;"     
     "movq %%rdx, %%r9;"  
     "adcq $0, %%r9;"              //A1*B0

     "movq 0(%1), %%rax;"  
     "mulq 8(%2);"         
     "addq %%rax, %%r8;" 
     "movq %%r8, 8(%0);"  
     "adcq %%rdx,%%r9;"    
     "adcq $0, %%r10;"                //A0*B1
                                     //1

     "xorq %%r8, %%r8;" 

     "movq 0(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 16(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r9;"            
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r10;"
     "adcq $0, %%r8;"           //A0*B2

     "movq 8(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 8(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r9;"            
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r10;"
     "adcq $0, %%r8;"        //A1*B1

     "movq 16(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 0(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r9;"    
     "movq %%r9, 16(%0);" 
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r10;"
     "adcq $0, %%r8;"            //A2*B0
                                 //2
     "xorq %%r9, %%r9;"  

     "movq 24(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 0(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r10;"            
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r8;"
     "adcq $0, %%r9;"              //A3*B0

     "movq 0(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 24(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r10;"            
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r8;"
     "adcq $0, %%r9;"            //A0*B3

     "movq 16(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 8(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r10;"            
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r8;"
     "adcq $0, %%r9;"        //A2*B1

     "movq 8(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 16(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r10;"   
     "movq %%r10, 24(%0);" 
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r8;"
     "adcq $0, %%r9;"        //A1*B2
                             //3


    /*About 1000 lines of omitted Assembly code is from here*/


     "xor %%r8, %%r8;"

     "movq 96(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 88(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r9;"
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r10;"
     "adcq $0, %%r8;"    //A12*B11

     "movq 88(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 96(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r9;"
     "movq %%r9, 184(%0);"
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r10;"
     "adcq $0, %%r8;"    //A11*B12
                         //23
     "xor %%r9, %%r9;"

     "movq 96(%1), %%rax;"
     "mulq 96(%2);"            
     "addq %%rax, %%r10;"
     "movq %%r10, 192(%0);"
     "adcq %%rdx, %%r8;"
     "adcq $0, %%r8;"    //A12*B12
                         //24

     "movq %%r8, 200(%0);" //25


     :  "=&r" (res->_mp_d) 
     : "r" ((ain->_mp_d)), "r" ((bin->_mp_d))
     : "%rax", "%rdx", "%r8", "%r9", "%r10", "memory", "cc"
     );
}
```

Comment: Too much inline assembly. Use it for the bare essentials, do the rest in C.

Comment: This level of unrolling is actually detrimental on x86-64 micro-architectures, as is 'Comba' (column-wise) multiplication.

Comment: @BrettHale - Thanks Brett. How are these things detrimental exactly?

Comment: It's better to have a fast row-wise 'mul-add' loop that fits in a cache line, with a highly predictable branch. The same is true with the row data. As well as Intel/AMD manuals, [Agner Fog's guides](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) are an excellent resource.

Comment: @Dieter - you might want to disassemble the object file and make sure `%0`, `%1`, `%2` are being substituted as expected. If the `r` constraint selects one of the registers that you clobber, it's probably going to be incorrect.

Comment: @BrettHale - I've tried replacing the `r` constraints with specific register constraints (`S`, `D` and b`) and I still get this weird behaviour. In fact the contents of array at `res->_mp_d` seem to change every time I display the contents. If I print out the contents immediately after the assembly code, I get the correct answer. However, if I print the contents of the array twice, consecutively, some of values will be incorrect the second time.

Comment: @BrettHale - Specifically, `(res->_mp_d)[0]`, `(res->_mp_d)[1]`, ... `(res->_mp_d)[5]` will change to (seemingly) random values every time I display the contents of `res->_mp_d`. The other entries in the array  do not seem to change.

Comment: Note that instead of calling mpz_mul, after a careful read of the doc (the args can be a bit strange), you could call directly mpn_mul, or mpn_mul_n (since both operands have the same size) or mpn_mul_basecase (since you know the operands are small). You may need to copy the declaration of that last one from the gmp sources as it is normally private. Now if GMP was compiled for your platform, this function is an asm loop hand-coded by a specialist specifically for your processor, that you'll have a hard time improving on.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly declare that res->_mp_d is an output of the asm statement, when it is actually an input that is a pointer to the output.